# Loading a class as a component in java

Tags: java, swing, reflection, components

I'm making a program that allows you to add any class file that extends `java.awt.Component` to a `javax.swing.JToolBar` in its main window. I made a test class that is simply an empty `javax.swing.JButton` called "test.class". How can I load this into the program as a component in my `javax.swing.JToolBar` when all I know is where on the computer this class file is stored?

Alternatively: Given that the final project is a single jar file (TinyExplorer.jar), and that this is in, say C:\Users\Username\Desktop\TinyExplorer.jar, where should the add-on class be placed and how should the jar look for it?

### Edit

---

I have implemented the following code:

```
      if (addOnFile.exists())
      {
        System.out.println(addOnFile.getName() + " is there!");
        java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(addOnFile);
        while (scan.hasNextLine())
        {
          String str = scan.nextLine();
          System.out.println(str);
          java.io.File f = new java.io.File(str);
          if (f.exists())
          {
            try
            {
              java.awt.Component comp;
              Class cls = Class.forName(str);
              Object obj = cls.newInstance();

              if (obj instanceof java.awt.Component)
              {
                comp = (java.awt.Component)obj;
              }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
              err.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

but every time I run it, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: G:\Java\NetBeansProjects\TinyExplorer\build\classes\testAddOn\test.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at explorer.Frame$24.run(Frame.java:1091)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue**

The issue here can be found from the following message in the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: G:\Java\NetBeansProjects\TinyExplorer\build\classes\testAddOn\test.class
```

This indicates that the code is trying to find a class name that's actually a file path to the `class` file. This is an incorrect usage of the [`Class.forName`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) method.

The *name* that the `Class.forName` method ([link to the Java API Specification of the method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)) takes is a *fully-qualified class name* of the class that should be loaded. For example, if we want to load the `JPanel` class, we'd have to provide `"javax.swing.JPanel"`, *not* a full path to the `class` file.

**The solution**

From looking at the code, the intention seems to be that the class contained in the `class` file with the full file system path of `G:\Java\NetBeansProjects\TinyExplorer\build\classes\testAddOn\test.class` should be loaded at runtime.

In order to do so, one must

1. Include the `class` file in the [classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).
2. Give the fully-qualified class name to the `Class.forName` class to obtain a `Class<?>` object.
3. Instantiate an object of the `Class<?>` using [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Performing (1) is going to be a requirement for the Java virtual machine to be able to find the class that should be loaded in (2) -- a `class` file that is not in the classpath is not going to be available during runtime.

Including the file in the classpath is usually going to be some type of build configuration in your IDE, or having to tell `javac` to add a [path to the classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Points (2) and (3) appears to be already partially implemented in the given code, and appears like it is heading toward the right path.

Comment: given that the final project is a single jar file (TinyExplorer.jar), and that this is in, say C:\Users\Username\Desktop\TinyExplorer.jar, where should the add-on class be placed and how should the jar look for it?

Comment: @Supuhstar: If the target class is included in the JAR, then as long as the JAR is in the classpath, then all that would be needed is the fully-qualified class name.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
Component comp = null;
String cls_name = "test";  // include your package ie "java.lang.String"

try {
    Class cls = Class.forName(cls_name);
    Object obj = cls.newInstance();

    if (obj instanceof Component) {
        comp = (Component) obj;
    }
}
catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}

setLayout(new BorderLayout() );

JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
if (comp != null) {
    toolbar.add(comp);
}

add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

`Class.forName()` and `Class.newInstance()` instantiate your new object.  The try block has a lot of potential for exceptions, and you may want to do better than a catch-all.  If your class doesn't have a default constructor, this won't work, and you'll need to get a Constructor object via reflection, and create the object by calling `Constructor.newInstance(...)`.

Comment: Thank you. This looks just perfect, and I'll try to see if this works. Now, I want to know... will this work if the name of the class is the path to it in the computer? That is how it is input.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html gives examples of how to add buttons. Suggest you get this running and working in your environment.You should then be ab le to extend this by analogy to your own compponents.

Comment: I know how to make components and add them to the toolbar; that's child's play. I want to know how to add a third-party class file to the toolbar as a component, when the only thing I know is where the class file is on the computer. Please read the whole question before posting an answer.

Comment: Please ask a clear coherent question before you be a jerk to people trying to decipher it.

Comment: I said nothing in my comment that was not said in the question

Comment: You added the statement that you want this for third-party components, not your own components. So don't be so quick to comment or judge when you don't ask a clear question, especially given your posting history of not bothering to read the API when you are given answers to questions.

Comment: @Supuhstar. @Falmani and @camickr make valuable comments. Your intitial post contained only 4 lines, badly phrased without a clear question. I tried to work out what you wanted - my answer was aimed at someone who might need help and not know the existence of the tutorial. There is no reason to be rude and downvote.